# Is kernel 5.10 available for downloading for old Amazon Linux?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

It appears i have an old Amazon Linux AMI, because i have Kernel 4.x version.

I need to upgrade the kernel, i have tried with the ELRepo, but i get stuck installing the repository (an issue with glibc version, it needs 2.28 and i have 2.26)

Is there's a way to update the kernel? or i will have to switch to the new AMI?
Can the AMI version get updated without losing all the data (instance AMI data)?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you are using Amazon Linux 1 AMI or Amazon Linux 2. For example, one of the currently supported Amazon Linux 2 AMI (ami-0a3c14e1ddbe7f23c) as noted in the Launch Wizard - provides Linux kernel version 4.14 which is also used by the last release of Amazon Linux 1. This is also slated for deprecation [per this article](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-linux-2-ami-kernel-5-10/) so I'm assuming this is what you're referring to. To confirm, you can check if you are running Amazon Linux 1 or 2 via the console or through the instance itself with something like:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
```

In the case of upgrading Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2: per [AWS Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/), there is no way to directly upgrade the kernel of an Amazon Linux AMI:

> Q. Can I perform an in-place upgrade from an existing version of Amazon Linux AMI to Amazon Linux 2?
>
> No, an in-place upgrade from the existing Amazon Linux image to Amazon Linux 2 is not supported. We recommend that you test your application on a fresh installation of Amazon Linux 2 first before migrating.

On the other hand if you are running Amazon Linux 2 with kernel 4.14, this should very much be possible by [installing and enabling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-repositories.html) through `amazon-linux-extras` and running the update using something like the following:

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install kernel-5.10
```

Pure speculation for this last part but I believe it is generally recommended to migrate your workload to the latest AMI if at all possible but this should be sufficient otherwise.